# Checking timestamps on multiple tables in ORDER BY with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Say I'm implementing a blog, and want to display the latest posts based on the latest activity (so the latest timestamp on a new post OR a new comment OR a new like).  My object structure is like this:

```
Post
 EntityCollection<Comment>
 EntityCollection<Like>
```

Right now, I'm ordering only by the latest timestamp on Post:

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts()
        {
            return from post in _db.Posts
                   orderby post.CreatedDate descending
                   select post;
        }
```

How can I modify this so that it checks the CreatedDate on the Comments and the Likes as well, so my ordering is based on latest activity and not just the Post createddate?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question (hence I'm commenting), but I would suggest that this might be something better handled by a SQL Server view or possibly a stored proceedure.  The SQL Server will be a lot more effecient at doing this kind of sorting, the LINQ-to-SQL query that is generated is likely to be quite nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a generic table called something like `Actions` or `Events` or something similar. This table should log every event that occurs - posts, comments and likes. The table contains *generic* information about each event. This information can for example include the time of the event, the type of event, the user id that initiated the event and a unique ID for the event. For more specific information about the event you will need to join to your specific tables using a foreign key constraint in the specific table which links to the generic table.

With this structure it is easy to fetch a list of all events in sorted order, and it will be efficient if the timestamp column in the generic table is indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the foreign key member in the Like table and Comment table called PostID,

```
List<Comment> lstComment
List<Like> lstLike
```

Change the query to:

```
var posts = from p in lstPost
            join c in lstComments on p.ID equals c.PostID
            join l in lstLikes on p.ID equals l.PostID
            orderby p.CreateDate, c.ActionDate, l.ActionDate
            select p;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks...this would probably be the easiest for me, but would the solution posted by @Mark Byers be a better long term solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use a modifiedDate on Post table and whenever a comment is added to that post update the modifiedDate to current time and use modifiedDate for sorting.